# Can someone translate this Chinese calligraphy into English?

Tags: translation, characters, character-identification

[image]

This was written by a relative of mine, Ahn Jung-Geun

Comment: You're related to the guy who assassinated Itō Hirobumi? How fascinating!

Comment: it is a matter of converting image to text, once this is done enter text on web and get details concerning this famous quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main text:

> **一日不讀書口中生荊棘**
>
> *Thorns will grow in your mouth if you go one day without reading/studying.*
>
> (하루라도 책을 읽지 않으면 입속에 가시가 돋는다)

The rest:

> 庚戌三月 扵旅順獄中 大韓國人 安重根 書
>
> Third month of **庚戌** (1910), Imprisoned at [Port Arthur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCshunkou_District), (written by) Ahn Jung-Geun, Citizen of the Korean Empire.

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 「於」and「扵」are variants which have the same definition. I chose「扵」because it's closer to the shape seen on the calligraphy sample. Note how the author writes the「方」in「旅」right underneath - he did not write「方」in「扵」.

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 blown up image: http://cfile229.uf.daum.net/image/245FCF3856F6498C106AEF compare left side of「扵」and「旅」.

Comment: @droooze, ok, after comparing, it's my mistake. my improper comment would be deleted.  sorry 

Answer (score -2):

这句话想表达的意思是：不读书就不会说话或说不出精彩的话。
类似于宋朝的名言“三日不读书，面目可憎” 。几天不读书，就感觉自己很很粗鄙。

Comment: The question was "translate in English".